# Misunderstanding in basic for loop (C)

Tags: c, for-loop

I have been going through some exercises from a recommended [book](http://knking.com/books/c2/index.html) I found on this website. I came across this following basic piece of code, which I could not fully understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int i;

for (i = 10; i >= 1; i /= 2)
    printf("%d ", i++);

return 0;
}
```

This is my reasoning behind this program fragment:

1. Variable `i` is initialised to `10`.
2. `i` is tested to see if greater or equal to `1`, (which is always the case).
3. The third expression reads: `i = i / 2`, thus `i` is divided by `2` and its value stored in `i`.
4. In the `printf` statement `i` is incremented *after* each `printf` statement.

I simply cannot understand why the output of this program is:

`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` ...

I get that the condition statement is always true, however shouldn't the first values be:

`5 3 2 1 1 1 1 1`?

Basically I cannot seem to understand why the value of `i` is straight away being stored as `1`. Any corrections regarding my reasoning and/or insight on the matter will be appreciated. Please do excuse the basic nature of this question.

Comment: The output is: `10 5 3 2 1 1 1 ...`:  See http://ideone.com/6qnGdC

Comment: Make sure i is an int. Check your binary (delete it then recompile and ensure the timestamp is right).

Comment: Show the whole code ([MCVE]).

Comment: It is just outputting too fast for you to see. Add an early exit `for (i = 10, int j = 0; i > = 1 && j < 10; i /=2, ++j )` and you will see: http://ideone.com/Ia4EqH

Comment: since it is a non-terminating loop, could it be that you've just lost the first outputs?

Comment: Whole code has been posted. I am using the exact same  code as @abelenky, therefore I am assuming that I am losing the first few outputs as @ Eugene Sh. pointed out. IS there any way not to let this happen on V.S 2015?

Comment: @Rizzo what do you want to happen? It stop when it reaches 1?

Comment: @clcto, I wanted to determine the output of this program, however I cannot seem to get to the beginning of the infinite loop.

Comment: just add a condition to terminate it after several iterations

Comment: Or run it and step through the code with the debugger. or add a sleep after it outputs. It is just executing too fast for you too see. As @MasPhysicist answers below, your deduction was correct besides `i /= 2` doesn't get executed until after the loop body.

Comment: @Rizzo: Aside from the suggestion to terminate it after several iterations, you can also just redirect the output to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @abelenky pointed out, the correct output is `10 5 3 2 1 1 1 ...`. The only mistake you made in your reasoning is that the statement `i /= 2` gets evaluated *after* the body of the for loop, before testing the condition again. Another way to write the same loop would therefore be

```
for(i = 10; i >= 1; i = (i + 1) / 2)
    printf ("%d ", i);
```

If you are running on Windows, try paging the output through `more`: `myprog | more`. This should allow you to see the beginning of the output of this infinite loop. On a linux machine, you could acheive the same result using `more` or `less`: `myprog | less`. Thanks to @EugeneSh for making the suggestion that this could be the issue.

Another way that I have found to view the initial output for programs like this is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> immediately after starting the program with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is not a "standard" method and may require very quick reflexes to get any results for a quick loop like yours.

A final suggestion is to limit the output you produce from the program directly:

```
int i, count;
for(i = 10, count = 0; i >= 1 && count < 100; i /= 2, count++)
    printf("%d ", i++);
```

This will add a counter that will stop your output after 100 numbers have been printed and allow you to see the first numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this matter. I am thinking that this is actually what is happening. I am running  on Visual Studio 2015, would there be a way to modify the settings of my console so that I can see the beginning of the output ? Or is the way you mentioned the only way to go ?

Comment: @Rizzo. I am not sure how to do it in VS, but you can always run it from the terminal, in which case my way will work.

Comment: @Rizzo. See additional edit. I think it may be the most useful to you since you can do it in VS directly.

Answer (score 0):

On the second line, you have 'i++'.
Thus at each iteration of the loop, it will also increment i by 1.

So supposing i = 1 when you start the loop. First it will be divided by 2 (i /= 2). Since i is an integer, it will become 0. Then, on the second line, you have 'i++', thus incrementing i.

So by the end of the loop iteration, i will be back to being equal to 1 (thus making this loop infinite).

Comment: While what you are saying is true, the OP already got that part and explained it themselves. This is not answering the actual question OP is posing at all.